# Python3 Selenium Module : Loop through list to add multiple values to form

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Currently I have a python script to add some values to a form that I need to loop through multiple times until all my tags and values are added (see screenshot of example data).

I've tested my script and have confirmed that everything gets added properly, now I just need to know if I should use a list or dictionary to loop through and if anyone could help me write out an example that would be even better.

```
#Clicks Add to add tags

time.sleep(1)
clickAddTags = browser.find_element_by_name('add')
clickAddTags.click()

#Values I want to add and loop through (need help here)
tagName = 'testing';
tagValue = 'testing';

time.sleep(1)
searchTagName = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#tagName')
searchTagName.send_keys(tagName)

tagValue = 'testing';
searchTagName = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#tagValue')
searchTagName.send_keys(tagValue)

#Clicks Add to add the tag
clickAdd = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('html body table tbody tr td form#mainForm table tbody tr#buttonbarbottom td.buttonbar input.bwbutton')
clickAdd.click()
```

Basically what this code does is click Add tags here - see screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sswXL.png)

Goes to the next screen to add the tagName and tagValues

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARsfs.png)

Clicks OK, and here is where I want it to click Add again and loop through and start adding the matching tag name to value.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up iterating through a dictionary

tagANDvalues = {
    'name1' : 'value1',
    'name2' : 'value2',
    'name3' : 'value3'
}

```
for tag, value in tagANDvalues.items():
    time.sleep(1)
    searchTagName = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#tagName')
    searchTagName.send_keys(tag)
    searchTagName = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#tagValue')
    searchTagName.send_keys(value)
    clickAdd = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('html body table tbody tr td form#mainForm table tbody tr#buttonbarbottom td.buttonbar input.bwbutton')
    clickAdd.click()
    time.sleep(1)
    clickAddTags = browser.find_element_by_name('add')
    clickAddTags.click()
```